# jQuery get aria-expanded attribute value

Tags: jquery

In the following code how to get the value of aria-expanded attribute. I have tried the following below

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#links_home" id="links_container" class="" aria-expanded="true">&lt;&lt;&lt;</a>
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#rules_home" id="rules_container" class="" aria-expanded="false">&lt;&lt;&lt;</a>
```

```js
function getaccordion_status() {
    var acc1 = "links_container";
    var acc2 = "rules_container";
    var arr = [acc1, acc2];
    arr.forEach(function(link) {
        toggle_accordion(link); 
    });
}

function toggle_accordion(link_id) {
    console.log("===============")
    console.log($("#" + link_id).children("aria-expanded").val());
    $("#" + link_id).each(function() {
        var ele = $(this)[0]['attributes'];
        console.log($(ele).children('aria-expanded').val())
    });
    console.log("===============")
}
```

Comment: you should use `.attr()` not `val()`

Comment: jQuery-UI or Bootstrap???

Comment: Sorry id was a type .Have corrected it please see the edit

Comment: @Rajeev is that what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/92/

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki : Some how this is not working as intended

Comment: So you have to add extra informations or we can't help from here.

Answer (score 4):

Try this simple function:

```
function toggle_accordion(link_id) {
   console.log($('a#'+link_id).attr('aria-expanded'));
}
```

Comment: did you try `prop()`?

Comment: No this is from bootstrap